# Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Tags: node.js, express, ionic2

> Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Here is my code:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
console.log("set views")
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: What do you actually try to do? Why are you using Ionic and Express at the same time?

Comment: Is this related to ionic at all?

Comment: this is my service code... i cant run in my browser

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by simply setting the views directly

```
app.set('views',
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be :

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname + '/views'))
```